# How to concat several dataframes in one dataframe with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have several dataframes with 5 rows and 5 columns. How do I concat them so they will on under each other (I want to build csv file out of that).
For example I have

df0

```
a/0/id a/0/team a/0/seed
6456   colorado  6
8978   oregon    7
0980   texas     1
```

df1

```
a/1/id a/1/team   a/1/seed
2342   nyc        12
8556   ucf        16
1324   california 5
```

How to get final dataframe like

final_df

```
6456   colorado   6
8978   oregon     7
0980   texas      1
2342   nyc        12
8556   ucf        16
1324   california 5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem different columns names, so need some preprocessing before `concat` - e.g. [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values by `/` and select last value - need same columns names for alignment in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df0.columns = df0.columns.str.split('/').str[-1]
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('/').str[-1]
print (df0)
     id      team  seed
0  6456  colorado     6
1  8978    oregon     7
2   980     texas     1

print (df1)
     id        team  seed
0  2342         nyc    12
1  8556         ucf    16
2  1324  california     5

final_df = pd.concat([df0, df1], ignore_index=True)
print (final_df)
     id        team  seed
0  6456    colorado     6
1  8978      oregon     7
2   980       texas     1
3  2342         nyc    12
4  8556         ucf    16
5  1324  california     5
```